# Integrate Over Multiple Columns in 1 List to Fill Additional List With Same Number Of Columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, scipy, numerical-integration

I am intending to take a list of random variables and alter a previous list in each column by said random variables. However, for the purpose of my function, each variable must be used in a Gamma function as well as integrated.

```
x[t] = c * (1 / (2 ** (v / 2) + test[t - 1]) * (gamma((v / 2) + test[t - 1]))) * integrate.\
                quad(lambda h: np.exp(-h / 2) * h ** ((v / 2) + test[t - 1] - 1), 0, np.inf)
```

x[ t ] is an np.zeros((x , y)) list, and test[t - 1] is an np.zeros((x - 1, y)) list

I have filled test[ ] with the appropriate random variables, but I am unable to pass them through this equation to complete the columns of row [ t ] in x

When I try to run my current code, I receive:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 450, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Is there a different special function which allows me to use each column's variable to solve for my desired x[ t ]?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import stats
import mpmath as mp
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.special import gamma

T = 1
beta = 0.5
x0 = 0.05
q = 0
mu = x0 - q
alpha = - (2 - beta) * mu
sigma0 = 0.1
sigma = (2 - beta) * sigma0
b = - ((1 - beta) / (2 * mu) * (sigma0 ** 2))
simulations = 100
M = 50
dt = T / M


def srd_sampled_nxc2():
    x = np.zeros((M + 1, simulations))
    x[0] = x0
    test = np.zeros((M, simulations))
    for t in range(1, M + 1):
        v = 4 * b * alpha / sigma ** 2
        c = (sigma ** 2 * (1 - np.exp(-alpha * dt))) / (4 * alpha)
        nc = np.exp(-alpha * dt) / c * x[t - 1]
        if v > 1:
            x[t] = c * ((np.random.standard_normal(simulations) + nc ** 0.5) ** 2 + mp.nsum(
                lambda i: np.random.standard_normal(simulations) ** 2, [0, v - 1]))
        else:
            max_array = []
            nc_over_2 = [l / 2 for l in nc]
            for p in range(simulations):
                sump = []
                poisson_start = 0
                while poisson_start <= 1:
                    x_i = sum(-np.log(np.random.uniform(0, 1, simulations)) / nc_over_2)
                    sump.append(
                        x_i
                    )
                    poisson_start += x_i
                x_n = max(sump)
                max_array.append(
                    x_n
                )
                sump = []
            test[t - 1] = max_array
            x[t] = c * (1 / (2 ** ((v / 2) + test[t - 1])) * (gamma((v / 2) + test[t - 1]))) * integrate.\
                quad(lambda h: np.exp(-h / 2) * h ** ((v / 2) + test[t - 1] - 1), 0, np.inf)
            max_array = []
    return x
```

Comment: Your problem here is that `test[t - 1]` is a list. quad expects a scalar. Can you advise what you actually want to do? Do you want to integrate for each value of test or something else?

Comment: I would like to alter each column in row `t` of `x[ ]` by the formula applied to each column of row `t - 1` in `test`. Essentially, use the number from each column of test to replicate the formula for `x[t]` "simulation" number of times, thus filling every single column of row t for `x[]`

Comment: I am getting some progress, but there is a problem with the while loop: for t > 2, x_i becomes way too small and it takes forever for poisson_start to reach 1. This is because the values in nc become huge, due to the previous x being very large, I guess because x_n is increasing. I can post the code if you want.

Comment: I found a way to properly store the integrals for each column and call them for `x[t]`, but I've also just realized that I should not be taking `x_n = max(sump)`; rather, I should take the length - 1, so `max_array.append(len(sump) - 1)`. The problem I seem to be facing now, is `x[t]` is far too small. The formula I'm using to sample a non-central chi-square is, for the most part, zero (given nc very large)
I also made sure that `test[t - 1]` was part of the power: `((v / 2) + test[t - 1])`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately ended up finding a workaround which is simple to implement:

```
        else:
            max_array = []
            for p in range(simulations):
                k = nc[t - 1, p]
                lam = k / 2
                poisson_samp = 0
                while poisson_samp <= 1:
                    x_i = -math.log(np.random.uniform(0, 1)) / lam
                    max_array.append(
                        x_i
                    )
                    poisson_samp += x_i
                test[t - 1, p] = len(max_array) - 1
                max_array.clear()
            for f in range(simulations):
                n = test[t - 1, f]
                z = integrate.quad(lambda h: np.exp(-h / 2) * h ** ((v / 2) + n - 1), 0, 1)
                new[t - 1, f] = z[0]
            x[t] = c * (1 / (2 ** ((v / 2) + test[t - 1]) * (gamma((v / 2) + test[t - 1]))) * new[0])
```

The only real problem is the shrinkage of `x[t]` which leads to dividing by zero--just a formula problem.